# 2 div aligned horizontally - Text going on new line in right div

Tags: html, css

I've two div aligned horizontally. I need to use them for a list, example:

```
Surname: Mario
Name: Rossi
```

These two divs are in a div which is 50% of my content, so I've also other content on the right. I've used "word-wrap:break-word;" to wrap the content in the right column of my list, but when it goes on new line, it produces something like this:

```
Surname: Mar
Name: io
        Rossi
```

While I want this result:

```
Surname: Mar
         io
Name: Rossi
```

How can I fix this?

My code:

css:

```
.left{
   width:50%;
   float:left;
   padding-right:10px;
   line-height:15px;
}
.right{
   width:50%;
   float:right;
   padding-left:10px;
   line-height:15px;
   word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

html:

```
<div>
    <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
        <div class="left">Surname</div><div class="right">Mario</div>
        <div class="left">Name</div><div class="right">Rossi</div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:50%;float:right;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe try `.left { clear: both }` ?

Comment: Your paddings are causing the issue.

Comment: Consider using `box-sizing: border-box` so the padding doesn’t increase your container width. [Article](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

Comment: @LeBen Problem isn't caused by paddings. The text can go on newline because there's no more space in the div because of "word-wrap:break-word;". I've tested removing the padding and it doesn't work.

Comment: @DaveGoten adding clear:both seems to work! :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j8rLuetw/1/ If you remove the padding it works..

Comment: @Press Text doesn't go on new line... I've situations in which the text CAN go to new line, because on the right of that box there're other things on the page.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.left{
   width:45%;
   text-align:right;
   float:left;
   line-height:15px;
}
.right{
   width: 45%;
   text-align:left;
   float:right;
   line-height:15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
        <div class="left">Surname</div><div class="right">Mario</div>
        <div class="left">Name</div><div class="right">Rossi</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This way u got 10% padding. Thats all.

Or you can add paddings with calc `width: calc(50% - 5px);` it will work too.

Comment: Problem isn't caused by paddings. The text can go on newline because there's no more space in the div because of "word-wrap:break-word;"

Comment: So maybe do it proper way with lists? <ul><li>Surname</li><li>Mario</li></ul>  . Set it to display mode: inline-block . It will behave as you expect.